# C# Selenium "nosuchelementexception" error

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I add “headless” to chromeoptions I get "nosuchelementexception" error but when I don't add, I don't get error.

When I remove the "headless" tag, it's running, but I don't want that. I want "headless" Google Chrome.

```
private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ChromeDriverService _chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    _chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
    ChromeOptions _chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    _chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("disable-infobars");
    _chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeDriverService, _chromeOptions);
}

private void btnGiris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://divvydrive.com/app/tr-TR/App/Transfer/MikroDrive");
    KullaniciAdiGirisi();
    DevamEtButton();
    KullaniciParolaGirisi();
    OturumAcButton();
}

private void KullaniciAdiGirisi()
{
    try{
        IWebElement _username = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"kullaniciAdi\"]"));
        _username.SendKeys(txtMusteriID.Text);
        listBCikti.Items.Add("Kullanıcı adı girildi.");
        listBCikti.Items.Add("");
    }
    catch (Exception exception){
        MessageBox.Show("Hata kodu; \n\n" + exception);
    }
}

private void DevamEtButton()
{
    try{
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        listBCikti.Items.Add("İşlem devam ediliyor...");
        listBCikti.Items.Add("");
        IWebElement _continuebutton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ileriButton\"]"));
        _continuebutton.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (Exception exception){
        MessageBox.Show("Hata kodu; \n\n" + exception);
    }
}

private void KullaniciParolaGirisi()
{
    try{
        IWebElement _password = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"sifre\"]"));
        _password.SendKeys(txtMusteriSifre.Text);
        listBCikti.Items.Add("Kullanıcı parola girildi.");
        listBCikti.Items.Add("");
    }
    catch (Exception exception){
        MessageBox.Show("Hata kodu; \n\n" + exception);
    }
}
```

I want to run Google Chrome in headless mode. If there are places you see wrong in my codes, I can also get suggestions. No problem at "KullaniciAdiGirisi", "NosuchelementException" error at "KullaniciParolaGirisi" step.

Error Code :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div/input"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=112.0.5615.87)'
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException means that it cannot find an element using the xpath you give it. I'd recommend a try catch loop for it, or use the `Polly` nuget package.

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: The XPath selector in the exception message does not appear anywhere in the C# code posted in this question. I would expected to see the XPath in the C# code if the exception truly originated in the code posted in this question.